# Independent Random Variables (Discrete Maths)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X1$ and $X2$ be independent random variables that are each selected uniformly at random
from the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$. Let $Y = max(X1, X2)$.

$(i)$ Find $Pr(X1 = 2 ∧ Y = 2)$

Question: I personally don't understand what does the max in function $Y$ means and how does $X2$ and $Y$ relate. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

$X_1$ and $X_2$ have each $3$ different outcomes, namely $1,2,3$. $Y$ is defined as the largest of the two results of $X_1$ and $X_2$. There are nine total results for $X_1$ and $X_2$, namely $(1,1), \ (1,2), \ \dots ,\ (3,3)$. For each of these results, $Y$ has a value ($1$ for the first, $2$ for the second, ... and $3$ for the last). This is how $Y$ and $X_1$, $X_2$ are related.

The question translates to: In how many of these $9$ cases is the first number a $2$ and at the same time the largest (or equal ) number of the two a $2$ as well?

Comment: so will that be (2,1) and (2,2) ?